# SQL Server Transaction Log VLF access

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to access, and examine the contents of, the VLFs (virtual log files) that make up sql server's transaction log?  I need this for a project to examine SQL Server's internal working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the behaviour of the VLFs is internalized within SQL Server's engine and there are no interfaces that expose their functionality or properties.